# Android studio not connecting my phone over wifi

Tags: android, android-studio

Pairing devices over wifi is so buggy on this Android studio. Sometimes it refuses to show a QR code, sometimes it shows the code but keeps saying an error occurred while connecting.

Even though my device has been connected several times before, it refuses to connect again. I have to delete the device from the list of devices in device manager of android studio.

Restarting laptop/android studio, phone/ etc resolves it, but I can't keep restarting everything for this stupid piece of software.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Run: `adb connect <IP address>:<Port>` in your terminal whenever your
> mobile fails to connect.
>
> You can find the IP and port in your phone's settings
> **Settings>Developer Option>Wireless Debugging.**

[Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247908/wireless-android-debugging-not-working)

Comment: i will try it next time android studio refuses to co-operate. Thanks!

Comment: adb command not found. i tried installing adb using this post, no luck. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager

Comment: I was able to make it work. but then got an error saying "failed to connect to 192........"

Comment: this adb and android studio is so frustrating to work with, huh

Comment: I used the pair command and it worked with the path to abd
/Users/<Username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb pair <IP address>:<Port>

Comment: Same with @Max i able to pair using adb pair IPAddr:Port and key in code. On my phone it showed device paired, but on Android studio, it isn't detecting my phone at all. So frustrating

Comment: When I did `adb pair IP:PORT`, it paired successfully but the port on device changed and the device never really connected. I did `adb connect IP:PORT` and it connected instantly and was also visible under Devices in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

First open your phone to the developer option and click on the wireless debugging and then click on pair device with pairing code. you will user the IP address and port show here.

In android studio open the terminal(Located bottom left). There you can run the following command.

```
/Users/<Username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb pair <IP address>:<Port>
```

running adb without the path did not work for me.  So I follow the path in the following location /Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools//Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb may be located in a different folder but it should be close to this location.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one of the devices (your computer or phone) needs the wifi to be reset. Turning your phone on airplane mode momentarily, or turning the wifi off on your computer momentarily, will usually reset the connection and allow Android Studio to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, once I made sure ADB worked within the Terminal embedded in Android Studio, pairing to WI-FI started working.

To get ADB to work within Android Studio, I added ADB as an environment variable:
https://theflutterist.medium.com/setting-up-adb-path-on-windows-android-tips-5b5cdaa9084b

After that I checked that ADB worked in the regular command prompt.

I then had to restart Android Studio, so that ADB also worked within Android Studio's embedded terminal.